# On what kind of condition of a compact set $K$ in the plane, $C(K)$ has a generator?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, real-analysis

Let $K\subset \Bbb{C}$ be a compact subset of the complex plane, and let $C(K)$ be the space of all complex continuous functions on $K$.

We say that $f\in C(K)$ is a **generator** of $C(K)$ when the set $\{p(f) \mid p\ \style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{is a polynomial}}\}$ is dense in $C(K)$.

If $K$ is any set consisting of finite points, it is easy to check that $C(K)$ has a generator.

If $K=[0,1]$, then we know that $f(x)=x$ is a generator of $C[0,1]$ by Stone-Weierstrass theorem. It follows that $C(\gamma)$ has a generator whenever $\gamma$ is a not a closed simple curve.

Now if $K=S^1$, the unit circle on the plane, then it has been proved that [$C(K)$ does not have a generator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670160/cs1-does-not-have-a-single-generator) It follows that $C(\gamma)$ does not have a generator for any $\gamma$ that is a simple connected curve.

If $K=\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, the unit disk, then by using [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), a similar method as in the case $K=S^1$ can be given to prove that $C(\overline{\Bbb{D}})$ does NOT have a generator. Similarly, It can be proved that $C(K)$ does NOT have a generator if $K$ has an interior point in $\Bbb{C}$.

How to solve this problem if $K$ does not have an interior point?

Comment: Already asked and answered on Math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671104/on-what-kind-of-condition-of-a-compact-set-k-in-the-plane-ck-has-a-genera

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm not convinced that answer is correct: cf. Lavrentieff's theorem which tells us that $P(K)=C(K)$ if $K$ has empty interior and does not separate the plane

Comment: Once we know that $C(S^1)$ doesn't have a generator, it immediately follows that $C(K)$ doesn't have a generator for any $K$ which contains a homeomorphic copy of $S^1$. Any generator of $C(K)$ would restrict to a generator of $C(S^1)$.

Comment: I'm not on MSE, but can someone who is on MSE put a note on the MSE question to point out that it is also being answered here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Yemon's conjecture is correct: $C(K)$ has a generator in the sense of the question if and only if $K$ has empty interior and $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ is connected. As he points out, the reverse direction follows from Lavrentiev's theorem. For the forward direction, if $K$ has nonempty interior then Mr. Li has already pointed out that we know $C(K)$ has no generator: this easily follows from [David Ullrich's answer to a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670160/cs1-does-not-have-a-single-generator) which says that $C(S^1)$ has no generator, and the fact that $K$ contains a homeomorphic copy of $S^1$.

Now suppose $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ is disconnected and assume $C(K)$ has a generator $f$. I claim that $K$ has a component $K_0$ such that $\mathbb{C}\setminus K_0$ is disconnected. Granting the claim, $C(K_0)$ also has a generator $f$, namely the restriction to $K_0$ of any generator of $C(K)$. It is obvious that $f$ must be 1-1 on $K_0$, so by a standard fact it is a homeomorphism between $K_0$ and $f(K_0)$. According to the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354119/are-the-complements-of-two-homeomorphic-compact-connected-subsets-of-mathbbr), $\mathbb{C}\setminus f(K_0)$ is also disconnected. Then $f(K_0)$ contains the boundary of a bounded open set, namely any bounded component of its complement. But now David Ullrich's argument for $S^1$ carries over verbatim to this setting to yield a contradiction. End of proof, modulo the claim.

To verify the claim, let $U$ be a bounded component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$, let $V$ be the unbounded component of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\overline{U}$, and let $K_0 = \partial V$.

Comment: @Nik.Using Lavrentiev's theorem again, this means that if $C(K)$ has a generator, then $z\rightarrow z$ is one of those generators.

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer: if $K$ has empty interior and ${\mathbb C}\setminus K$ is connceted then Lavrentiev's theorem tells us that $P(K)=C(K)$. (See e.g. Gamelin's book on uniform algebras.) In such cases the function $z\mapsto z$ is a generator of $C(K)$ in the sense of your question.

In view of Nik Weaver's observation in the comments I am inclined to guess that this sufficient condition on K is also necessary but I currently don't have time to think about this further.

Note, in view of glenlair's answer and the comment on MSE, that there are obvious examples of such $K$ which are not homeomorphic to subsets of the real line. For instance, take three copies of $[0,1]$ glued together at $\{1\}$ in a tripod shape. This is a compact connected space with the property that removing a certain point leaves three connected components. But compact connected subsets of the real line are closed intervals (or singleton sets) and in those cases removing a point can leave at most two connected components.

Comment: @Yemon.yes,that is a partial answer. Define$K^{+}=\{z\in \Bbb{C}\mid |p(z)| \le ||p||_{K} $ for every polynomial p $\}$. Then the assumptions of Lavrentiev's theorem is equivalent to $K=K^{+}$.

Comment: The converse (that $z$ is a generator if and only if $K$ has empty interior and $\mathbb{C}-K$ is connected) does not seem very hard; if $K$ has non empty interior then it contains a disk and hence any generator would give a generator for the algebras of funtions on the disk. if $\mathbb{C}-K$ is not connected, then as it is open it has open connected componenent, only one of them can be unbounded, and if $U$ is a bounded connected component then the uniform norm of a polynomial on $U$ is controled by its uniform norm on the boundary of $U$ which is in $K$ hence...

Comment: ... the algebra generated by $z$ is contains in the algebra of function that can be extended into a holomorphic functions on $U$. so $f$ is a generator of $C(K)$ if and only if $f(K)$ has empty interior and does not disconect $\mathbb{C}$, but does it implies that $K$ itself satisfies those hypothesis ?

Comment: @SimonHenry Yes, this is roughly where I had got to in my thinking

Answer (score 0):

One can get a purely topological characterisation of such compacta by combining two facts.  Firstly, $C(K)$ is singly generated if and only if $K$ is homeomorphic to a subset of the reals.  Secondly, subsets of the reals, even without compactness, have been characterised topologically by several  authors (see, for example, M.E. Rudin, P.J.M. 7 (1957), 1185-1186).

Comment: is it complex or real $C(K)$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov It must be real-valued in glenlair's reference, because of Lavrentiev's theorem as mentioned in my answer below